# GNU Make: different dependencies of several binaries in the same target?

Tags: c, makefile, dependencies, target

First of all, I'm not familiar with GNU Make, so if I state some concept ridiculously wrong, please correct them instead of teasing me, thanks.

I want to have a default target that builds several executables with different dependencies, but I can't figure it out. Here is a minimal example I am using:

```
    CC = gcc-4.8
    CFLAGS = # some compiler flags
    LDFLAGS = # some linker flags
    SOURCES = prog1.c prog2.c
    OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
    TARGET = prog1 prog2

    $(TARGET) : $(OBJECTS)
            $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o prog1 prog1.o $(LDFLAGS)
            $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o prog2 prog2.o $(LDFLAGS)

    .PHONY: clean

    clean:
            @rm -f $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) core
```

But, as you can see, though `prog2` is not at all related to `prog1.c`, editing `prog1.c` will result in the relinking of `prog2`. Is there any way to prevent this?

(Also, I would really appreciate it if someone can direct me to a good tutorial to GNU Make. The official documentation is huge...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each target has to have its own set of prerequisites; if you write:

```
foo bar: biz baz
```

that means "foo depends on biz and baz, and bar also depends on biz and baz".  You want to write:

```
prog1: prog1.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)
prog2: prog2.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)
```

Alternatively, you can write both targets in the same rule and define the prerequisites separately:

```
prog1 prog2:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)
prog1: prog1.o
prog2: prog2.o
```

There are lots and lots of ways to make this more sophisticated and reduce typing.  That's kind of what make is all about.

**Update**:

To build two targets at the same time by default, use

```
all: prog1 prog2

prog1 prog2:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)
prog1: prog1.o
prog2: prog2.o
```

where `all` is the first target.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but your solution creates two targets; only the first one can be default, and the second one needs to be manually invoked by `make prog2`. The ideal situation is to type `make` once and build both executables, just like in the example I gave above (though dependency is weird). According to your answer, seems that the ideal situation is not achievable?

Comment: Make by default builds the first (non-rule) target it finds.  If, therefore, you have a target `all: prog1 prog2`, then `make` or `make all` will build the `all` target, which means it must first build the `prog?` targets, which is what you're looking for.

Comment: @KevinSayHi Next time you propose an edit like that, please write that it comes from the comment thread with the poster of the answer, so we know where it does come from! Else it's most likely to get rejected.